# reciprocally VS. mutually

Tags: difference, vocabulary, comparison

Would anyone please more **readily** explain if there  is any difference between these? and if they are interchangeable?

A mutually beneficial/supportive relationship

A reciprocally beneficial/supportive relationship

“For example, in the early Middle Ages a Romance ethnic unity, in the absence of any political bond, linked nations of the most varied origins. ***Reciprocally***, on the question of ethnic unity, we must first consult language. ”

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Mutual and reciprocal can be easily confused in certain contexts. The clearest explanation I've found is from the [Synonym Study section for Mutual on Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mutual).

> *Mutual*, *reciprocal* agree in the idea of an exchange or balance between two or more persons or groups. Mutual indicates an exchange of a feeling, obligation, etc., between two or more people, or an interchange of some kind between persons or things: mutual esteem; in mutual agreement. Reciprocal indicates a relation in which one act, thing, feeling, etc., balances or is given in return for another: reciprocal promises or favors.

The main idea behind reciprocal is "if you do this, I will do that in return" and the main idea behind "mutual" is "we both are part of the exchange of something". We might give reciprocal gifts (I give you a gift because you gave me one) and have mutual feelings of good will (we both have a balance of good feelings toward each other).

In your example sentence:

> “For example, in the early Middle Ages a Romance ethnic unity, in the absence of any political bond, linked nations of the most varied origins. **Reciprocally**, on the question of ethnic unity, we must first consult language. ”

Here, "Romance" refers to Romance languages. Earlier in the passage the author writes *"In general, ethnic unity always suffices to explain linguistic community."* So, if we want to discuss ethnic unity, we should in turn discuss language and if we want to discuss bonds of a common language, we should in turn discuss ethnicity. The reciprocal relationship is "if we do this, we should do that, and if we do that, we should do this".

Another example:

*Because both countries were determined to **reciprocate** with greater force if they were attacked, their **mutual** destruction was inevitable once the first attack was launched.*

Answer (score 1):

A *mutually* beneficial relationship is one that provides some benefit to both parties, though that benefit may be different or to different degrees. For instance, I get access to your oil, and in return, I defend your borders. (You get something from me, and I get something from you, but they're different.)

A *reciprocally* beneficial relationship is one that benefits both parties in basically equal measure. For example, we agree that people from both our lands can freely cross the border in either direction to facilitate trade and tourism relations. (You get something from me, and I get something of equal value from you.)

In certain situations, they could be used interchangeably, but probably not as a general rule. Additionally, you will hear "mutually beneficial" much more frequently.

Comment: First, thanks. But, would anyone please show me another example to the point, in such a way that I could get my original question better?

Answer (score 1):

The word "mutual" refers to something that is in some way shared between two or more parties. But it does not need to be the exact same thing for both or all parties.

For example:

- A bee and a flower are said to have a **mutual dependence**. The bee feeds on the nectar of the flower, and spreads the pollen so that the plant can reproduce. Each gets something, but not the same thing.
- During the Cold War, the US and USSR had a policy of "Mutually Assured Destruction": If either started a nuclear exchange, both would surely be destroyed.
- Some insurance companies are known as "mutual" companies, because the profits are shared among all the policy holders. like a co-op.
- A relationship may be "mutually satisfying" if both (or all) parties gain something satisfying from it, but it may not be the same thing, nor of equal importance to each.
- A mutual guarantee is a situation where each party guarantees the performance of the other.

Thus a "mutually beneficial relationship" is one where both (or all) parties benefit, but the benefit may not be of the same kind or size

The word "reciprocal" refers to a situation in which something goes back and forth between two (and normally exactly two) parties, or in which very similar things go back and forth.

The [Merriam-Webster definition of reciprocal](http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocal) lists as senses:

- inversely related : opposite
- shared, felt, or shown by both sides
- serving to reciprocate : consisting of or functioning as a return in kind
- mutually corresponding

Some examples would be:

- The treaty imposes reciprocal obligations on A and B.  A has the same obligations to B that B does to A. It is an even exchange.
- The warring parties engaged in reciprocal  violence. A did to B pretty much what B did to A.
- We have a reciprocal  arrangement: I sit for her children on Mondays and Wednesdays, and she sits for mine on Tuesdays and Thursdays.
- A Teeter-totter has a reciprocal  movement, one side goes up when the other goes down, and vice-versa. The pistons in an automobile engine also have a reciprocal  movement, one goes up as the other goes down.
  *prosperity and crime have a reciprocal  relation, as prosperity goes up, crime goes down.

Thus a "reciprocally beneficial relationship" is one in which A does for B much the same as what B does for A.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to give you what I think or perceive as the right, easy to understand definition ***in pure lay man's terms,*** without using the words Reciprocate or Mutual to show differences. In actuality, though, they are synonyms with same, if not implied meanings.

**reciprocate** : Always provokes or leads to a reaction. Good or bad. Kinda Tit for Tat attitude. You scratch my back, I scratch your back (in action/deed/spoken/what you say or do etcetera). Not necessarily in equal measure.

I texted/called him regularly, but he never called/texted back. (did not reciprocate). I will not text him anymore. (Tit for Tat)

Tom surprisingly gave me a Birthday gift. I have to do the same for his birthday. (reciprocate Tom's doing)

Japan bombed Pearl Harbor, so America bombed  Hiroshima and Nagasaki in response (reciprocated)

I slapped him, and he immediately slapped and kicked me back.(reciprocated action)

**Mutual :unprovoked** not previously agreed upon but equal, more natural-like attitudes/ habits, feelings, responses, etcetera. Not necessarily in equal measure.

I love my girlfriend, and she loves me just as much, if not more. (mutual, not prompted, naturally happening)

My wife wanted to visit Paris and I thought that was a great idea. We both love Paris. Paris was our common choice (mutual).

I believe that in defining any word, the word to be defined should not be used to define it. or else there is no point in explaining it.

I hope that helped.

Comment: I fear this fails to make the **difference** in meaning clear. And there is a difference, these are **not** synonyms, although they are closely related.

Comment: All dictionaries name the two as near synonyms, since they are so close in what is meant in their usage, hence they may be termed as implied meanings besides several other words. But, in the end,  I guess  it's a matter of personal interpretation of the two words. Of course, there is a difference. But they are a very close call.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutual does not mention "reciprocal" ;  nor does https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocal#synonyms mention "mutual" The latter gives the key synonym of "Inverse". All that said, in many contexts the two have significantly overlapping meanings.